# TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Anybody?

Tags: python, selenium

I keep on getting issues with a part of my code. Anybody has some idea how to tackle it?
Python - Selenium

**I added the full code. The purpose is to auto open Instagram Stories.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random
import string

#Chromedriver path. Make sure to have the same Chromedriver version as your Google Chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"")  # <----- ENTER PATH HERE 

browser.get(('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher'))
sleep(2) 
        
def start():
    acceptCookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[1]');
    acceptCookies.click();
    sleep(4);
    #browser.implicitly_wait(3)  #this is another wait function.If you would like to run the script faster, change all sleep() to this
    username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username.send_keys('') # <- INSERT YOUR INSTAGRAM USERNAME HERE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.send_keys('') # <- INSERT YOUR INSTAGRAM PASSWORD HERE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button')
    nextButton.click()
    #browser.quit()
    sleep(5)
    notification = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Niet nu')]")
    notification.click()
    sleep(5)
    notification = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Niet nu')]")
    notification.click()
    sleep(5)

def openStories(self):
    bot=self.bot
    bot.find_element_by_xpath('OE30K').click()  

    
#Start the programm
start()
openStories()
```

Comment: Can you provide the full class declaration?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide more context on your code and what you are trying to do and include the rest of your class if you can.

Comment: Usually the keyword `self` is used for class methods to reference the instance, so that method can only be called without any argument if it's within a class.
If you define it outside a class then you must pass a argument.

Answer (score 0):

In Python `self` is used this way:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None: # constructor
        self.age = age # self is the object that the constructor is initializing
        self.myMethod(name) # You can call methods passing the instance itself as argument, the argument 'self' is the instance
    def myMethod(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

The `self` variable represents the instance itself.

```
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> my_object.myMethod('myName')
>>> print(my_object.name)
'myName'
```

The `self` argument is the instance on which the method is called.

Comment: Methods belong to classes, not instances. There is no instance attribute named `myMethod` defined for `my_object`, so the lookup algorithm starts checking classes in the MRO, starting with `MyClass`, for a class attribute named `myMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understand the difference between defining a method within a class and a function outside a class.

```py
class MyClass:
    foo = "HELLO!"

    def openStories1(self):
        # Here self is an instance of MyClass
        print(self.foo)

def openStories2(self):
    # Here self is just an object.
    print(self.foo)

# Can be called without explicitly passing an argument, since self refers to the instance1
instance1 = MyClass()
instance1.openStories1()

# When defining outside a class you will need to pass the instance explicitly.
openStories2(instance1)

# Raises error since this function cannot be accessed through the instance because it's not defined in the class.
instance1.openStories2()
```

Outputs:

```sh
HELLO!
HELLO!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_6.py", line 18, in <module>
    instance1.openStories2()
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'openStories2'
```

Comment: I updated the code. If someone knows how to get it working, please help me edit the code. Thanks community!